# Динамическая смена ItemsSource в TabControl (Коллекции разных типов)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

Есть задача, отображения коллекции данных отфильтрованных и разделённых на 5 вкладок.

Например есть коллекция сериалов и в каждой вкладке либо запланированные к просмотру, либо просмотренные, либо брошенные на середине.
Есть также коллекция комиксов, с точно такой же сортировкой по вкладкам. 
Приложение отображает либо список сериалов, либо список комиксов. 
У сериалов есть помимо прочего поле "Серии", у комиксов же вместо этого есть поля "Главы" и "Тома". То есть классы для них различаются.

Нужно, чтобы программа работала в одном из двух режимов (либо только для комиксов, либо только для сериалов). Кнопки переключения есть в главном меню.

**Вопрос:** можно ли подобное реализовать с помощью одного TabControl, при условии следования паттернам MVVM?

Сейчас это реализовано следующим образом:

```
    <TabControl SelectedIndex="1" Name="animeTabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding AnimeLists}" Height="250" Visibility="{Binding Mode.AnimeVisibility}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding URStatusRus}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding List}" MaxHeight="250">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridView.Columns>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Name"        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Episodes"    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Progress}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Score"       DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Score}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Kind"        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Kind}" />
                            </GridView.Columns>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
    <TabControl SelectedIndex="1" Name="mangaTabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding MangaLists}" Height="250" Visibility="{Binding Mode.MangaVisibility}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding URStatusRus}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding List}" MaxHeight="250">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridView.Columns>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Name"        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Chapters"    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProgressCh}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Volumes"     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProgressVol}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Score"       DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Score}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Kind"        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Kind}" />
                            </GridView.Columns>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, я использую 2 TabControl'а и в зависимости от режима отображаю лишь один из них. Не знаю, на сколько правильный такой подход, поэтому и спрашиваю совета у SO.

Comment: Если правильно понял суть проблемы, то можно использовать селектор шаблона (`DataTemplateSelector`)

Comment: @Ev_Hyper а можно чуть подробнее?

Comment: что именно подробнее написать?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper что это и как им пользоваться?

Comment: Вы запрос в гугл не можете самостоятельно составить или что? Не надо ждать, что на каждый ваш чих (читай вопрос) пользователи побегут строчить ответы на несколько абзацев. Вы MCVE написали? Нет. Так с чего вы взяли что для вас будут персонально писать пример.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper я всего лишь попросил наводку на информацию, потому что не сразу понял о чём речь. После того, как я написал комментарий, я загуглил и кажется нашёл то, что нужно. Извините, если чем-то вас обидел.

Comment: Последнее дело обижаться на подобные комментарии ;) Лишь пытаюсь донести мысль что самостоятельный поиск намного более эффективное средство для обучения чем вопросы к другим пользователям. Намного лучше формулировать вопрос по типу: "Я искал информацию по поводу ..., но нашел только это (ссылка)  но не уверен, что это то что мне нужно, так как ..." а не просто "а можно подробнее?"

Comment: @Ev_Hyper: Как известно, поиск в гугле обычно ведёт назад на StackOverflow.

Comment: @VladD это смотря что искать. Можно ничего не найти, т.к. не искать, а можно искать и все равно ничего не найти. Не против второго, наоборот всячески приветствую, т.к. умение задавать правильные вопросы приходит только с опытом

Comment: @Ev_Hyper: Вот вам официальное обсуждение на английском SO. Там отношение к отсылкам в Гугл намного более жёсткое, чем то, что написал я. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8724/154101 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15650/154101

Comment: @VladD вы сейчас пытаетесь донести мысль, что отсылать пользователей в гугл неправильно? Полностью поддерживаю.

Comment: мне показалось, @Mr. Modest , что вы правильно поняли мысль... Но учитывая комментарии выше на всякий случай повторю основную мысль. Хотелось бы, чтобы в следующий раз последовательность ваших действий была не: `После того, как я написал комментарий, я загуглил и кажется нашёл то, что нужно.` а `1. гугл 2.комментарий`. Цените свое и чужое время. А если первоначальный комментарий был резковат, то не обижайтесь, ни в коим случае не хотел вас задеть.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper: Её самую, да.

Comment: @VladD тогда вы не по адресу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно обойтись с использованием `ContentControl` и заданием `DataTemplate` для каждого объекта(для сериалов и для комиксов).

Создадим базовый класс представляющий собой родителя для комиксов и сериалов.

```
public class BaseVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     //какие-то свойства
     //реализация INotifyPropertyChanged
}
```

Создадим производные классы:

```
public class MangaVM : BaseVM
{
     public ObservableCollection<тип_комикса> MangaList { get; set; }
}

public class AnimeVM : BaseVM
{
     public ObservableCollection<тип_сериала> AnimeList { get; set; }
}

public List<BaseVM> Entertainments { get; set; } //список который будет в меню выбора
public BaseVM SelectedEntertainment { get; set; }//выбранный элемент в зависимости от которого
                                                 //будет меняться шаблон представления
```

теперь XAML:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MangaVM}">
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MangaList}">

    </TabContol>
</DateTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AnimeVM}">
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding AnimeList}">

    </TabContol>
</DateTemplate>
```

Элемент описывающий меню с выбором я сделал в качестве `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Entertainments}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntertainment}">
     <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemsPanel>          
</ListBox>
```

Теперь сам `ContentControl`. `ContentControl` сам подберет нужный шаблон представления в зависимости от типа привязанного элемента свойству `Content`

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedEntertainment}"/>
```

P.S. Ваша реализация со сменой контролов через `Visibility` имеет право жить. Так как, при смене `Visibility` не происходит повторно отрисовка контрола, в отличие от `ContentControl` при смене `Content`'a.

Такое решение я применяю когда контрол сложный, содержит много дочерних элементов.

Comment: Хорошее стандартное решение, селектор тут конечно был бы лишним - а все из-за того, что вопрос понял неправильно :(

Comment: Спасибо за подробный пример. Разве что, селектор мне не нужен, смена у меня просходит по команде, которая описана в VM =)

Comment: @Mr.Modest, вы хотели получить ответ можно ли подобное сделать с одним TabControl? Если да, то в зависимости от выбранной категории нужно менять ItemsSource у него.

Comment: Хотя шаблон для Items разный, поэтому так просто не получится, лучше использовать 2 TabControl.

Comment: Ваш пример хорош, разве что я планирую попробовать реализовать это привязав к `<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentListVM}"/>` базовый класс и нужный шаблон, по идее, должен будет меняться в зависимости от того, какой из типов будет в CurrentListVM, если мне верно подсказали) пока нет времени, но как будет поверю)

Comment: да, можно и ContentPresenter. Не совсем понял про "базовый класс будет меняться в зависимости от типа CurrentListVM". а так все верно, шаблон будет меняться)